# Setting attribute for anchor tag child node with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, anchor

I am trying to access a specific anchor tag and give it a specific attribute using jquery. So far I have been able to give all the anchor tags the attribute. If I wanted to only give the 'aria-label' attribute to the 2nd or 3rd li anchor tag, I assumed I would pass an argument of [1] or [2] somewhere within the query code but have not been successful in doing so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Jquery Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Accessing specific elements Jquery</h1><hr>
    <div id="parent-div">
        <ul id="child-div">
            <li id="grandchild-1">
                <a href="https://www.google.com/"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-chain"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="grandchild-2">
                <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript">
                    <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="grandchild-3">
                <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp">
                    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="grandchild-4">
                <a href="https://jquery.com/">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#parent-div').parent().find('li>a').attr('aria-label','Test');
    }); 
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply target the a's directly within the li's? If you inspect the "a" elements - you can see the aria attribute has been applied.

EDIT - an array of strings has been added and the loop altered to apply a different label to each li > a as per discussion in comments. Each indexed label is shown in the console to demonstrate the outcome and inspecting the a elements will show the individually assigned aria-label.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   const labels=["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];

    $('#parent-div li > a').each(function(index){
      const ariaLabel = labels[index] + ' label';
      
      $(this).attr('aria-label',ariaLabel);
      
      console.log(index,  ariaLabel)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <div id="parent-div">
        <ul id="child-div">
            <li id="grandchild-1">
                <a href="https://www.google.com/"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-chain"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="grandchild-2">
                <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript">
                    <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="grandchild-3">
                <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp">
                    <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="grandchild-4">
                <a href="https://jquery.com/">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes the attribute gets applied to all of the anchor tags. I would like to apply a specific attribute to each one like aria-label

Comment: @FullStack2016 - all you have to do is to iterate over the elements and paply a designated label to each - instead of the same label to all. But it will be the aame concept - just indivisuated to each iteration - eg you could have an array of labels and for the index of each iteration (ie the first li >a, the second li > a etc - pass it the different label based on the index.

Comment: @FullStack2016 - I have amended my solution to provide and array of label strings and each is applied to a different li > a based on the li index.